# Angular 4: Debug the AOT build process

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-aot, angular-aot

Angular version: **4.3.2**

Node: **v8.11.2**

TypeScript: **2.3.3**

While creating the AOT build using , I am facing issue as follows:

```
Error in (some index.ngfactory.ts file with path having $$_gendir): Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormGroup'
```

[image]

As can be seen, the file having issue seem to belong to some temporary location, may be some in-memory file.
Wanted to check if it is possible to access it in some way to guess what can be the issue and correct in source code accordingly.

Thanks.

Comment: can you try using a recent Angular version? Currently it's v7, this behaviour might have been fixed

Comment: @JeremyThille: Not an option for me, as it is a pretty bigger application to update the Angular Version. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you know any way so as to keep the ngfactory file after build attempt is interrupted by the specified error?

Comment: No sorry, no clue :/